# ASP.NET параметр в button CommandArgument

Tags: c#, asp.net

Хочу передать текст из LabelFrom и LabelTo как параметр в OnClick.

```
<asp:Label ID="LabelFrom" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="LabelTo" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:Button ID="ConcatConditions" runat="server" Text="Слияние без удалением старого" CommandArgument='<%#Eval(LabelFrom.Text) + ";" +Eval(LabelTo.Text)%>' OnClick="ConcatConditions_Click" />
```

Значение Label задается в js:

```
  document.getElementById("<%= LabelFrom.ClientID %>").innerHTML = idFrom;
  document.getElementById("<%= LabelTo.ClientID %>").innerHTML = idTo;
```

На сервере:

```
 protected void ConcatConditions_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      var btn = (Button)sender;
      var arg = btn.CommandArgument.Split(';');
  }
```

В CommandArgument, LabelFrom.Text, LabelTo.Text всегда пустота. 
Подскажите в чем проблема!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что при отправке данных на сервер передаются только значения из полей `<input>` формы. Элемент `<asp:Label>` рендерится в тег `<span>`, соответственно, его значение на сервер не отправляется.

Можно передать данные на сервер в скрытом поле. Добавьте на форму `<asp:HiddenField>`:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="LabelValues" runat="server" />
```

Скрипт:

```
document.getElementById("<%= LabelFrom.ClientID %>").innerHTML = idFrom;
document.getElementById("<%= LabelTo.ClientID %>").innerHTML = idTo;
document.getElementById("<%= LabelValues.ClientID %>").value = idFrom + ';' + idTo;
```

Обработчик на сервере:

```
protected void ConcatConditions_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var arg = LabelValues.Value.Split(';');
}
```

Параметр `CommandArgument` вам в принципе не нужен.